# How to join tables with multiple statements using SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime, join, date-arithmetic

In SQLite, my goal is to combine Table 1 and Table 2 to create Table 3 (see Desired Table 3 below). For context, delivery date/time is always before arrival date/time, and the arrival date must be 7 days after the delivery date. If delivery and arrival are the same dates, the delivery time must be before arrival time (see pacakge_ID 90 & 56 for reference). I have tried the code below, but it did not give the desired Table 3. The result gave me package_ID 90, 56, and 20, instead of the desired Table 3. However, my code successfully removed ID 67. What other statements do I need to add for the code? I hope this is clear as I am new here.

Table 1:

| package_ID | delivery_DATE | delivery_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 2020-09-08 | 2:09:34 |
| 90 | 2020-03-03 | 9:49:39 |
| 67 | 2020-07-04 | 10:08:00 |
| 20 | 2020-05-07 | 11:08:01 |

Table 2:

| package_ID | arrival_DATE | arrival_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 2020-09-08 | 0:00:00 |
| 90 | 2020-03-03 | 13:00:09 |
| 67 | 2020-07-31 | 12:32:45 |
| 20 | 2020-05-14 | 9:08:10 |

Desired Table 3 (after coding):

| package_ID | delivery_DATE | delivery_TIME | arrival_DATE | arrival_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 2020-03-03 | 9:49:39 | 2020-03-03 | 13:00:09 |
| 20 | 2020-05-07 | 11:08:01 | 2020-05-14 | 9:08:10 |

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT *
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.package_ID=table2.package_ID AND delivery_DATE BETWEEN DATE(arrival_DATE,'-7 day') AND arrival_DATE 
AND TIME(delivery_TIME) < TIME(arrival_TIME) 
ORDER BY package_ID DESC;
```

Comment: What was wrong with the result you got from your query? Did it have a duplicate package_Id  column? (column names must be unique) Di you try selecting each field: `select table1.package_Id, delivery_DATE, delivery_TIME, arrival_DATE, arrival_TIME...`?

Comment: The result gave me package_ID 90, 20, and 56, instead of just 90 and 20.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the dates have the format `YYYY-MM-DD` and all the times have the format `hh:mm:ss` (your sample data contains times that don't have this format), then you must concatenate date and time in the conditions of the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.arrival_DATE, t2.arrival_TIME
FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 
ON t2.package_ID = t1.package_ID 
AND t1.delivery_DATE || ' ' || t1.delivery_TIME 
    BETWEEN 
      date(t2.arrival_DATE, '-7 day')  || ' ' || t2.arrival_TIME
      AND 
      t2.arrival_DATE  || ' ' || t2.arrival_TIME
ORDER BY t1.package_ID DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=6c48fd5ee7bd3e60d8cd15c25e54e396).